# Copy folder to folder

Tags: batch-file

How can I get this to copy folder "contact" inside folder "bruker"?

I only get it to copy files inside "contact" to "folder"

```
if exist %USERPROFILE%\Contacts\ xcopy "%USERPROFILE%\Contacts\" "%Backupusb%\Backup\BRUKER\" /e
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the folder name to the destination path?

```
if exist "%USERPROFILE%\Contacts\" xcopy "%USERPROFILE%\Contacts\" "%Backupusb%\Backup\BRUKER\Contacts\" /e
```

Comment: Will this create the Contact folder? Because I think I tried this but then I got "folder doesn't exist"  Maybe I did something wrong...

Comment: It does create the Contact folder if you end it with `Contacts\ `, if you just have `Contacts` without the ending `\ ` then you get a prompt to say if you meant it to be a folder or a file.

Comment: Great! Il try, Tanks!

Comment: Now i have tried this`if exist %USERPROFILE%\Contacts\ xcopy /s /e /c /y  "%USERPROFILE%\Contacts\" "%Backupusb%\Backup\BRUKER\Contacts\" ` It gives me an error  " 0 files copied, unknown path"

Comment: xcopy takes the source and destination as the first parameters; try putting the `/s /e /c /y` at the end: `if exist %USERPROFILE%\Contacts\ xcopy "%USERPROFILE%\Contacts\" "%Backupusb%\Backup\BRUKER\Contacts\" /s /e /c /y`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use:

```
if exist "%USERPROFILE%\Contacts" %SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe "%USERPROFILE%\Contacts" "%Backupusb%\Backup\BRUKER\Contacts" /E /C /I /Q /H /R /K /Y >nul
```

`Contacts` must be also specified in target directory path.

Parameter `/I` tells command **xcopy** that `Contacts` is a directory which should be created if it does not already exist.

For the details of all used parameters of **xcopy** open a command prompt window, enter and execute in this window `xcopy /?` and read the help output for this command in console window.